# How to log out from OneNote 14.0?

Tags: onenote, office-2010

I have `Windows 7 Professional` operating system on my computer. I am using `OneNote 14.0` as part of `Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010`. I have a personal account attached to it; I created notebooks in it and saved them on my `OneDrive` and they sync good so everything is working ok.

Now I want `OneNote 14.0` to stop using my personal account so I am looking to log out of my personal account from it. But I could not find how to do that. I can click on `File --> Share` menu option to open **Share Notebook** tab; in there in the 3rd section **Web Location**, I can click on *Not myName* link but nothing happens and I stays in. Very frustrated. Please help.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, but does File | Account show the right UI for you?